# Navigation Title not showing

Tags: uinavigationcontroller, swiftui

So at first I wanted to get rid of the Navigation bar from the home screen as it does not want to show the title & I don't really need it.

However I can't remove it because I use `NavigationLink`. So I am left in a little pickle.

How do I either hide the toolbar/navigation bar on home page or show the title.

MIN CODE

```
struct ContentView: View {
    

   var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
          
                Text("Loading")
          
        }.navigationBarTitle(Text("Home"))
    }
}
```

So after a few more attempts seems that the title had to be shown in

```
  var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            
            if posts.isEmpty {
                Text("Loading")
                //.navigationBarTitle("") //this must be empty
                .navigationBarHidden(true)
                      
            } else {
                  (REST OF CODE)
            }
    }
   }
```

Still can't hide it though. The issue is it keeps disappearing when the if statement runs.

Comment: Would you minimise example to testable to reproduce your issue?

Comment: done @Asperi hope that helps

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `.navigationBarTitle`, as well as other similar modifiers, should be used **inside** `NavigationView`, like

```
struct ContentView: View {
   var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
           Text("Loading")
            .navigationBarTitle(Text("Home"))    // << here !!
        }
    }
}
```

**Update:** if you want to make modifier work for both condition branches wrap condition into some container (`VStack`, `Group`, etc.), like

```
var body: some View {
   NavigationView {
      Group {         
        if posts.isEmpty {
            Text("Loading")
        } else {
              (REST OF CODE)
        }
      }
      //.navigationBarTitle("") //this must be empty
      .navigationBarHidden(true)    // << here !!
   }
}
```

Comment: I found out that it was not really the positioning that was the issue, it was because of the if statement that we had.